# Phonemes and phonemic sounds

Tags: terminology, phonemes

How is called the property of phonemes due to which one minimal pair is enough to establish the phonemic status of a sound?

Comment: The principle is called ***contrast***. Two sounds that contrast are distinct phonemes; otherwise no one could tell them apart and they would not contrast. _Phonemes contrast_ is certainly true, and arguably primal.

Comment: I wouldn't call contrast a *principle*, rather, it's a property sometimes held by two sounds in a language.